# How can I get the latest browser version with JS?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to get the latest browser version number programatically with javascript. For example, when someone is visiting my site with Chrome, I want to know "Which is the latest version of Chrome available?"

I tried using `navigator.userAgent` but the returned information only contains the current browser version which the visitor has installed.

Is there any way to get the information about the latest browser version? I don't want to use static variables for it.

Comment: What do you mean - "last version"?

Comment: The last version of the browser installed? Or anything else?

Comment: For example, now I use Chrome (ver.56), but the latest version is 65. How I can get it by JS?)

Comment: I think there is no service that provides this information. You have to collect this information, store it into an persitence and create an own API to receive this information.

Comment: There is actually services that could do this - F.ex this small js script : https://browser-update.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API:

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/static/main/api-docs/v2/swagger-ui/index.html

The API is free, easy to set up and provides the latest version numbers for the most popular web browsers.

I hope that works for you! Keep rocking